# On the debugger the metadata are correct, when I share the link they are completely broken

Tags: facebook

I'm having some problem with links preview when sharing on facebook.

I tried the debuger tool, and:

- the scraped data are *correct*
- it throws an error about the image being too small (it's 1200px X 700px X 90KB)
- but it shows it in the image thumbs
- it show it even in the final preview of "*When shared, this is what will be included*"
- title and description are perfect

But if I click on "*See this in the share dialog*" it shows me the wrong image, and ok, but the title is missing!
I even html encoded it to be sure.

This is the url to be shared http://www.zucchinaverde.it/locale.asp?t=3/4%20Divino&dove=Palermo&i=443EDB94

This is how it must looks and how it looks in the debugger
[image: Preview]

This is how it looks when shared
[image: *]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `og:url` set in your page is `http://www.zucchinaverde.it/locale.asp?i=443EDB94` which differs from the URL that you have using `http://www.zucchinaverde.it/locale.asp?t=3/4%20Divino&dove=Palermo&i=443EDB94`. This will be treated as a redirect which causes the crawler to fetch the data from the redirected URL. You need to ensure that they are the same and then `Fetch new scape information` in the URL debugger to update the scraped data. I forced a re-scrape to the redirected URL and it seems to be working now but ensure that the values are same to avoid these errors.